# Is it possible to use 'IN' in command "SHOW COLUMNS" MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the list of columns with needed type but when I try use this command

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table_name` WHERE `Type` IN ('int', ''varchar)
```

it's not working

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Yes but it's not working. I think problem in block  IN because after write type i should write leng for this type. I tried IN ('int%', ''varchar%') but it's also work only with LIKE

Comment: Post an example.

Comment: Well I believe the type is stored as `varchar(20)` and `int(10)` for example.  So you must use `LIKE 'varchar%' OR LIKE 'int%'`

Comment: I suppose you did see the TYPO?

Comment: If your problem is resolved, please select the answer that 
best suits you by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might have more luck querying the underlying table directly.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
     WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' 
     AND DATA_TYPE IN ('int', 'varchar');
```

Answer (score 0):

For IN you have to specify the complete types.
example:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM konf
WHERE Type IN ('int(11)','VARCHAR(16)')
```

Or you can use Like as mentioned in the comment.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM konf
WHERE Type LIKE 'int%' OR TYPE LIKE 'varchar%'
```

( tested with MariaDB 10.2.29 ))